# gWidgets: how to embed from other packages?

Tags: r, gwidgets

If there is a way to embed in `gWidgets` objects from other packages.
For example from the package `utils`.

```
options(guiToolkit = "RGtk2")
library(RGtk2)
library(gWidgets)
library(gWidgetsRGtk2)

library(utils)

w <- gwindow() # gwindow {gWidgets}
e <- edit(InsectSprays) # edit.data.frame {utils}
```

Comment: `edit.data.frame` returns the edited data frame.  I guess you mean "can you embed R's dataviewer into a gWidget window".  In which case the answer is probably not.

Comment: You are right. The answer is probably not. My question comes from the idea a widget to incorporate objects from other packages. Anyway, TNX

Comment: There's no reason why you can't mix and match gWidgets GUIs with things created elsewhere: you just can't have them in the same window.  So you can have a gWidgets button that clicking opens the R dataviewer window, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible as `gWidgets` supports only objects of the certain class like `gButton`, `gWindow` etc. `gWidgets` does not contain documented functions to import \ embed external library \ package GUI objects. E.g.

```
options(guiToolkit = "RGtk2")
library(RGtk2)
library(gWidgets)
library(gWidgetsRGtk2)

library(utils)

win <- gwindow("Window example",
               handler=function(h,...) {
                 print("See ya")
               })
but <- gbutton("cancel", container=win,
        handler = function(h,...) dispose(win))

str(but)  # gButton class object structure

# Formal class 'gButton' [package "gWidgets"] with 2 slots
# ..@ toolkit:Formal class 'guiWidgetsToolkitRGtk2' [package "gWidgets"] with 1 slot
# .. .. ..@ toolkit: chr  ...
# ..@ widget :Warning in str.default(obj, ...) :
#   'str.default': 'le' -- это NA, так что беру как 0
# Formal class 'gButtonRGtk' [package "gWidgetsRGtk2"] with 3 slots
# .. .. ..@ block  :Classes 'GtkAlignment', 'GtkBin', 'GtkContainer', 'GtkWidget', 'GtkObject', 'GInitiallyUnowned', 'GObject', 'RGtkObject' <externalptr> 
#   .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "interfaces")= chr [1:2]  ...
# .. .. ..@ widget :Classes 'GtkButton', 'GtkBin', 'GtkContainer', 'GtkWidget', 'GtkObject', 'GInitiallyUnowned', 'GObject', 'RGtkObject' <externalptr> 
#   .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "interfaces")= chr [1:3]  ...
# .. .. ..@ toolkit:Formal class 'guiWidgetsToolkitRGtk2' [package "gWidgets"] with 1 slot
# .. .. .. .. ..@ toolkit: chr  ...
```

moreover after execution of the code the code returns control to the R programming environement.

In contrast `utils::edit` function returns the `data.frame` object and suspend R execution environement.

Based on the comment jverzani, the new version of the package `gWidgets2`  allows to get access to the underlying widgets if you want to integrate into other GUIs. Using `gWidgets2`'s `getToolkitWidget` method it is possible to attach underlying GUI items into a layout, the `add` method should work.

Comment: You can get access to the underlying widgets if you want to integrate into other GUIs. Using gWidgets2, makes this easier, as there is a `getToolkitWidget` method. If you want to attache underlying GUI items into a layout, the `add` method should work.

Comment: Thanks, I'll added to the body of the answer.